# Css sibling (~) selector doesn't work with checked property

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't my css below work for me? Can anyone advise me please.

```
#slide1:checked ~ #inner { margin-left: 0;}
#slide2:checked ~ #inner { margin-left: -800px;}
#slide3:checked ~ #inner { margin-left: -1600px;}
```

The css below does work. I don't know where to go from here.

```
#slide1:checked ~ #broadControl label:nth-child(1),
#slide2:checked ~ #broadControl label:nth-child(2),
#slide3:checked ~ #broadControl label:nth-child(3){
    background: #333;
    border-color: #333; !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="broadcast">
    <div id="overflow">
        <div id="inner">

            <article>
                <div class="info"></div>
                <div id="pic1"></div>
                <!--img src=""-->
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="info"></div>
                <div id="pic2"></div>
                <!--img src=""-->
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="info"></div>
                <div id="pic3"></div>
                <!--img src=""-->
            </article>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Broadcast controls -->
<input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
<div id="broadControl">
    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a slide transition with pure CSS to understand more in CSS.

But I've been stuck here for 3 days now.

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

If you have any ideas, please suggest them to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#slide1:checked ~ #broadControl label:nth-child(1)
```

The `~` operator only works on elements AFTER the element. In this case, `#slide1` searches for `#broadControl` label elements AFTER `#slide1`, it cannot search before it.

**Example Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/9vxYJ/

You will see in that fiddle that i moved your `#broadcast` portion to AFTER the `broadcast controls`.

the other issue is that `~` is a *sibling selector*, which means it can only find elements on the same level. But you can work around this, since `#broadcast` IS on the same level as `#slide1` etc., you can bury into `#inner`, like so:

```
#slide1:checked ~ #broadcast > #overflow > #inner { margin-left: 0;}
#slide2:checked ~ #broadcast > #overflow > #inner { margin-left: -800px;}
#slide3:checked ~ #broadcast > #overflow > #inner { margin-left: -1600px;}
```

Comment: @JongzPuangput I've updated my answer with more details and an example fiddle. The issue you mention there is because `~` is a sibling selector, and `#inner` is not a sibling of `#slide1`, but I've added a solution for you.

Comment: MANY MANY MANY THANK @Jace !!!

You save my life ^____^

Thank you for your example and you explanation.

Comment: @JongzPuangput I'm very very glad it helped you :) If you feel it appropriate, consider upvoting and marking as answer.

Comment: I don't konw what is Fiddle but it seem very useful tool for explanation, edit and testing. Thank you for your solution again @Jace 

Best Regards